# AWS EC2 ENA Support on Linux; Unable to connect after changing instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm in the process of upgrading several of our EC2 instances from type T2 to T3. This requires enabling ENA support. I've successfully upgraded 3 of 4 instances, but the last one is having issues.

I've enabled ENA, just like the other instances, changed the instance type to T3.2xlarge, and started the instance. When I attempt to SSH into it, SSH attempts to make the connection to the instance but gets no response. I get the same result trying to make it an M5 or M4 instance as well. However, starting it as a T2 or M3, I'm able to connect to it just fine.

The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS and ENA support is enabled:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-xx-xx-xxxx:/$ modinfo ena
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-150-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/amazon/ena/ena.ko
version:        2.0.3K
license:        GPL
description:    Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)
author:         Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates
srcversion:     E19C939F9F1A3B8E900815D
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd0000EC21sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd0000EC20sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd00001EC2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001D0Fd00000EC2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-150-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)

ubuntu@ip-172-xx-xx-xxxx:/$ aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-000scrubbed000 --query "Reservations[].Instances[].EnaSupport"
[   
    true
]
```

Anyone have thoughts/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58810971/2992786, basically you can run  Amazon's NitroInstanceChecks script that verifies and solve potential issues when migrating to nitro based instances.
In my case it was related to the fstab file that was solved by NitroInstanceChecks script.